# How to set color to every widget in GTK

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I want C code for setting color of every widget in GTK.

Comment: What is a BE student?  Bachelor of Engineering?

Comment: All well and good, but please check the help section of the site: show what you've tried, what you've researched, and explain why you want to do it this way

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid hardcoding colors of GTK+ widgets from the code. See for instance [this article](http://ometer.com/gtk-colors.html) for some discussion of the available methods.

[This blog post](http://eric.extremeboredom.net/2005/01/10/107) explains why sometimes, you simply can't (not all widgets actually render to "their" background pixels).

I think you should consider re-designing your application so you don't need to hardcode the widget colors, or see if the RC-based route can work for you.